# Gitlab / You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK component

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

При сборке проекта по автоматическому файлу **.gitlab-ci.yml** для android.

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2, Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2].   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Read more about this script on this blog post https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/, by Greyson Parrelli
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.1"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
  - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test

functionalTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
    - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-x86-google_apis-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
    - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -n test -t android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK} --abi google_apis/x86
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - ./gradlew cAT
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что проблема в том, как принять соглашение в неинтерактивном режиме?

Comment: @nick-volynkin, судя по переводу, да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На данный момент Google рекомендует такой способ:

1. запускаете на обычной машине с установленным Android SDK в папке проекта `./gradlew build`
2. содержимое `$ANDROID_HOME/lisenses` помещаете в соответствующую папку на билд-машине (у меня там `android-sdk-license` и `android-sdk-preview-license`)

В вашем случае можно положить эти файлы в репозиторий (например, в папку `sdk-licenses`) и добавить `mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/ && cp sdk-licenses/* $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/` в `before_script`

UPDATE:
в репозитории не должно быть файла `local.properties`, потому что параметр `sdk.dir` в нем имеет приоритет над `$ANDROID_HOME` для Gradle.

Comment: "1" - запускать в папке с проектом? Если да, то где файл потом брать. "2" - в папке где sdk есть "lisenses", 1 файл. "cp в before_script" можно уточнить?

Comment: @LyaoChin уточнил ответ

Comment: 2) У меня на локальной машине только "android-sdk-license".
Создал папку "sdk-licenses" и поместил в неё файл "android-sdk-license". Так же добавил строку в "before_script". Я так понял, что нужно добавить строку в конец "before_script".
Ошибка: cp: cannot create regular file '/builds/lyaochin/ver24/android-sdk-linux/lisenses/': Not a directory

Comment: После добавлений:-mkdir $ANDROID_HOME/lisenses/
-cp sdk-licenses/* $ANDROID_HOME/lisenses/ Ошибка: The SDK directory '/home/sfd/Android/Sdk' does not exist.
Только я не понимаю, почему ошибка у меня на локальной машине, а не на сервере gitlab?

Comment: как-то странно у вас сменился путь с `/builds/lyaochin/ver24/android-sdk-linux/` на `/home/sfd/Android/Sdk`. посмотрите обновленную команду в ответе

Comment: По пунктам: 
1. Импортирую проект с github(example android).
2. Создаю в master файл  .gitlab-ci.yml по автогенерации.
3. Жду сборки по сгенерированному скрипту?  Это должно было собрать проект?

Comment: если в импортируемом проекте приложены лицензии от sdk в папку и прописано их копирование в папку сдк билд-машины. иначе при старте сборки попросит принять лицензию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69150/discussion-between-lyao-chin-and-dekanszn).